# Envío de vars XMLHttpRequest , variable vacía en php enviada desde javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Al pasar unas variables desde JavaScript a php a través de XMLHttpRequest , hay una de ellas que parece que no la envía ó la envía vacía ya que me da el error ya que al cargar la página, me da éste error:

> [Mon Aug 22 12:32:58 2016] [error] [client 10.32.153.159] PHP Notice: Undefined variable: callFunction in /APRMARA/home/proactiv/Desarrollo/web/mapas/inicio_pru.php on line 210, referer: https://10.15.112.69/desarrollo/mapas/frames1_td_json_fr_pru.php

EN JS:

```
   onCreateLabel: function(label, node){
    label.id = node.id;            
    label.innerHTML = node.name;
    label.onclick = function(){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "inicio_pru.php";
    var JSONstr = JSON.stringify(json);

    var params = "callFunction=anade_rama&json="+JSONstr+"&node_id="+node.id;**
     http.open("POST", url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
      http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the statechanges.
     if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

     json=http.responseText;

     }
   }

     http.send(params);
```

En php:

```
   <?php

      if (isset($_GET["id_arbol"])) {
       $tipo_var=$_GET["id_arbol"];
       $desc_var=$_GET["id_desc"];
   };

    if (isset($_POST['json'])){

      $callFunction = $_POST['callFunction'];
      $jsonString=$_POST['json'];
      $node_id=$_POST['node_id'];

    };
 //etc 
 //:

      if($callFunction == "anade_rama") {  //se queja aquí
```

Comment: Hola, donde pones `JSON.stringify(json)` no se ve donde se define la variable `json`.  ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo real del contenido.? ademas, tienes dos asteriscos `**` al final de esa linea, ¿es un error al copiar o estan en el codigo fuente? Gracias

Comment: Sugerencia, deberías definir un valor por defecto o en que `isset($_POST['json'])` de falso para `$callFunction`.

1. Definiendo un valor por defecto antes del `if`.
2. Definiendo el valor dentro del `else`.

Y en el `else` del `if($callFunction == "anade_rama")` podrías armar un respuesta de error para que reciba el cliente. 

También de momento puede hacer un dump de $_POST (con `var_dump` o `print_r`) a fin de ver que parámetros recibió PHP.